# Aligning text without tabs - java

Tags: java, spaces

Hey every one I just need some help with formatting some code, I'm supposed to make a table, however I can't seem to get the alignment correct.  So far this is the code I've gotten:

```
 public class assignment2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int line = 0;
    int down = 0;
    int num =0;


    for (line = 1; line < 21; line++){ 
        System.out.print("     " + line );  //prints the numbers across with 5 spaces

    } 
        System.out.print("\n");  //moves the compiler to a new line, same thing as System.out.println 


    for (down = 1; down <= 20; down++) { //prints out the numbers down with 4 spaces to the first number 
        System.out.print(down + "    "); 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){ //Counter to stand in place for the x-axis numbers
            num = i % down; 
            if (num != 0) { 
                System.out.print("    "); // 5 spaces, checks to see if the number are multiples of each other 
                if (i > 9){
                    System.out.print(" " ); //1 spaces, also aligns the numbers going diagonally 
                }
                } else {
                if (i >= 10){
                    if (i % 2 == 0 ) { 

                        System.out.print("E"+"      "); // 6 spaces 
                    } else  
                        System.out.print("O"+ "      "); // 6 spaces

                } else {
                    if (i % 2 == 0 ) { 
                        System.out.print("E"+"     "); // 5 spaces
                    } else { 
                        System.out.print("O"+ "     "); // 5 spaces

                    }
                } 
            }
            if (down >=2){
                System.out.print(" "); // 1 space 
            }
            if (i == 20){
                System.out.print("\r\n");
            }
        } 

    } 
}
```

So far the text looks like this: [Screen shot of display with code playing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF1wO.png) 
  Any help would be appreciated, it you can point in the right direction and point out any mistakes I've done in the code it would be great appreciated!

Comment: You may want to take a look at the System.out.format() and System.out.printf() methods.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is not use spaces at all. Simply use the Tab tag (**\t**), like this:

```
System.out.print("\t" + line);  //for your top line
```

Now when you want to apply either **E** or **O** you can do:

```
System.out.print("\tE");
```

OR

```
System.out.print("\tO");
```

If however, for some unknown reason you are not allowed to use the Tab tag (\t) then you can utilize the **String.format()** method in place of the Tab tag, like this:

```
System.out.print(String.format("%"+spaces+"s", "E"));
```

where the **spaces** variable would hold the number of spaces you want to left-pad your text. A possible rendition of your task may look like this:

```
int line, down, num, spaces;
for (line = 1; line <= 25; line++){ 
    System.out.print(String.format("%6s", line));  
} 
System.out.print("\n");  
for (down = 1; down <= 25; down++) { 
    System.out.print(down); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++){ 
        num = i % down;
        if (down > 0 && down < 10 && i == 1) { spaces = 5; }
        else if (down > 9 && i == 1) { spaces = 4; }
        else { spaces = 6; }
        if (num != 0) { 
            System.out.print(String.format("%"+spaces+"s", " ")); 
        } 
        else {
            if (i % 2 == 0 ) { 
                System.out.print(String.format("%"+spaces+"s", "E"));
            } 
            else { 
                System.out.print(String.format("%"+spaces+"s", "O"));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

But...then again...you're probably not allowed to use the **String.format()** method either :/

Comment: Problem is I'm not allowed to use the tab function at all, so I have to figure out how to do with spaces instead

Answer (score 0):

I just created your program. To align the text I had to do. Do a similar thing for "O" and for the cases where neither "E" nor "O."

```
System.out.print("E");
System.out.print("     ");   
if(ii >= 10)
{
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

> I used one nested for loop with a bunch of if else statements to complete the program :

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numberEntered; i++)
{
    for(int ii = 0; ii <= numberEntered; ii++)
    {
         //A bunch of code here
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```